The application cant be installed because it is incompatible with the device 0xC7D24FBC
We need to deploy an app with M365 Intune (MDM Kiosk) on a Tablet. The tablet is enrolled correctly, the app is detected, it tries to install and ends up returning this error message.
I found this solution, browsing the Internet, but I can't get it to work. Thank you!
The tablet we are trying to push the app doesn't support the
uses-permission call_phone.
Remove that permission in the manifest, or try to add:

I'm trying to be able to enroll the tablet in kiosk mode and have the APK automatically deployed to all the devices we need.

Did your firm develop the APK in question? Or is this some APK from some other organization?

We have developed it in the Company, correct. At first there was a problem with the Manifest and the publication. We have achieved it, it is published in Intune, we managed to synchronize it so that it is installed on the enrolled device until we reach this error. Thank you!

Presumably, your app manifest contains:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

This not only says that you want permission to place phone calls, but it implies that you want this app only to run on devices that can place phone calls.
Your developers will need to decide if the app can possibly work on that tablet, since the tablet cannot place phone calls. And, if the app is supposed to work on this tablet, the developers will need to change that app according to the instructions, to both say "we do not absolutely require call-phone capability" (via a <uses-feature> manifest element) and code to avoid trying to place phone calls on this tablet (via calls to PackageManager and its hasSystemFeature() method).
